# Utility patent and method patent

Tags: patentscope

In the course of solving a problem a new [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(patent)) was developed.   To support the method, a novel measurement device was required and developed.  Assume that the

- methods
- device

must work together to deliver the claims associated with the patent.  It would seem necessary to file all methods and required novel support-device under one patent to ensure that claims are supported.

As I understand it both would fall under utility patents (method and machine respectively).  In what situations would it make sense to disclose these method and device under a single patent?  Likewise, in what situations would it make sense to disclose under two different patents?